# Apache virtualhosts are not processed if request headers are malformed

Tags: apache, virtualhost, http-status-code-400

I have Apache/2.4.46 (Ubuntu) configured with two virtualhosts. Let's say the default (first) virtual host is [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and the other is beta.example.com. If I do a request to the latter with malformed headers, e.g.

```sh
 curl -H 'Content-Length: 0' -H 'Content-Length: 0' https://beta.example.com/
```

I will get the Apache error page with title `400 Bad Request` as expected. However, the address line in the page has `Apache/2.4.46 (Ubuntu) Server at www.example.com Port 443` instead of the expected beta.example.com.

My assumption is that the header validity is checked before virtualhosts are processed, and since headers are not correct virtualhosts are never processed and the default one is used. Is this the case? If yes where is this behavior configured and is there a way to show the correct server address in the error message?

EDIT:
Please see [this Github repo](https://github.com/samuliasmala/apache-vhost-issue) for Dockerfile and instructions how to replicate the issue.

Comment: Work fine on my virtualhosts, please share your config.

Comment: The real config files are quite large but I was able to create a minimal config to replicate the issue. Please see the repository I added to the original question.